# RabbitMQ, topic exchange

Tags: java, android, rabbitmq, rabbitmq-exchange

I have a Topic Exchange on my RabbitMQ. 
An error by sending a message.

```
EXCHANGE_NAME = "EX_TEST";
```

Receive Section:

```
ConnectionFactory connectionFactory = new ConnectionFactory();
connectionFactory.setHost(mServer);
mConnection = connectionFactory.newConnection();
mModel = mConnection.createChannel();
mModel.exchangeDeclare(EXCHANGE_NAME, MyExchangeType, true);
mQueue = mModel.queueDeclare().getQueue();
MySubscription = new QueueingConsumer(mModel);
mModel.queueBind(mQueue, EXCHANGE_NAME, routingKey);
mModel.basicConsume(mQueue, true, MySubscription);
```

Send Section:

```
ConnectionFactory factory = new ConnectionFactory();
        factory.setHost("localhost");
        Connection connection = factory.newConnection();
        Channel channel = connection.createChannel();
        channel.exchangeDeclare(EXCHANGE_NAME, "topic");
```

error on line: `channel.exchangeDeclare(EXCHANGE_NAME, "topic");` 
Exceptions:
cannot redeclare exchange 'EX_TEST' in vhost '/' with different type, durable, internal or autodelete value, class-id=40, method-id=10

How to resolve this?
thankyou :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Method arguments in

```
mModel.exchangeDeclare(EXCHANGE_NAME, MyExchangeType, true);
```

and

```
channel.exchangeDeclare(EXCHANGE_NAME, "topic");
```

should be identical.